# Problem file to import not found or unreadable ../../variables/_colors.scss

Tags: drush, theming

I'm currently using Omega 4 with Sass, compass, breakpoint, singularity.

When I run the command drush omega-guard, I have the error below.
Any body know what could be the problem.

It's like there is a problem with globbing.

I'am on Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks a lot

```
error sass/layouts/header/header.layout.scss (Line 1 of sass/variables/**/*: File to import not found or unreadable: ../../variables/_colors.scss.
    Load paths:
      /var/www/vhosts/nexera.linuxlocal.com/sites/all/themes/nexera/sass
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/compass-0.12.6/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/compass-normalize-1.5/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/compass-rgbapng-0.2.1/lib/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/breakpoint-2.0.7/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/singularitygs-1.1.2/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/compass-blend-modes-0.0.2/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/color-schemer-0.2.8/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/toolkit-1.3.8/stylesheets
      /home/beach/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass
      /var/www/vhosts/nexera.linuxlocal.com/sites/all/themes/nexera/sass
      Compass::SpriteImporter
      Sass::Globbing::Importer)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change gem 'sass-globbing' to gem 'sass-globbing', '1.1.0' in your Gemfile and then run bundle install